# How to create an Eclipse plugin from existing project

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I have a project in Eclipse and I would like to turn this project into a plugin. I see some examples of how I can create a plugin from scratch and use a plug in template, but what I actually want is for one of the projects in my workspace to be packaged into a plugin.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is far too broad. The amount of work varies enormously depending on the sort of project. Something with a GUI, for example, would probably need to be substantially rewritten.

Comment: You can't package a project into a plugin.  You must start from scratch using a plugin template.  Unless Eclipse has changed plugins recently, you can't even upgrade a plugin.  You have to start from scratch using a more recent plugin template.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc What you are saying makes no sense to me. What do you want to upgrade and what's stopping you? Why a template? What is your point?